# MySQL trouble inserting row when using php

Tags: php

I am trying to insert a row into my table tutorial_info using the command:

```
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO tutorial_info(tutorial_id,tutorial_title,tutorial_author,submission_date)
         VALUES(NULL,"Math","Bob Trotter",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

 if($conn->query($sql3)===TRUE){

     echo "Added data\n";

   }

    else echo "Could not add data to the table ".$conn->error;
```

The insert function is not working. I am not getting any error displayed at all.

`$conn` is my mysqli object. I have managed to get other queries working on `$conn`. I have also cut and paste

```
INSERT INTO tutorial_info(tutorial_id,tutorial_title,tutorial_author,submission_date)
             VALUES(NULL,"Math","Bob Trotter",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

directly into MySQL to confirm the syntax is correct and it works.

Any tips on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: you have problem here `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";` look at the end

Comment: @shehary, there's absolutely nothing wrong with that bit.

Comment: @Styphon, May be, i never seen this `;";` before but php is what sky is the limit :)

Comment: @shehary that's because most people don't terminate their MySQL statements. The first semi-colon terminates the SQL query, the quote ends the string and the second semi-colon terminates the PHP line.